# Alpine plant identification

Tags: alpine

I was hoping someone could help me identify this plant.  The photo was taken in The Lofoten Islands in Norway, on an alpine environment.  [image: Alpine Plant]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Ajuga pyramidalis - native to Europe, it grows wild in parts of Scandinavia, see here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajuga_pyramidalis

Comment: Thank you very much, I spent the best part of an hour looking in all the wrong places for that!

Comment: This is the most close identification I'll also have, because the habits, but but: the colour of petals (blue and white), and most important: in the photo we see stolons. Maybe it is just nordic-only species

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi your eyes must be better than mine, cos I can't see stolons... whereabouts in the pic can you see those? If it has stolons, then it might be Ajuga pseudopyramidalis (but there'd have to be Ajuga reptans in the vicinity for it to hybridize in that way, see here) http://wildflowerfinder.org.uk/Flowers/B/Bugle(Pyramidal)/Bugle(Pyramidal).htm

Comment: @Bamboo: the plant on the right side, you see that the steam originate from the main plant (the steam is curved). But also the most near one, it is too near to rosette leaves. There could be other reasons, but I give 90% that the plant has stolons.Considering also the colour of flowers. Hybridation is also a good point

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I get it, you're assuming there must be stolons because of the other growth/s. Well  in might be pseudopyramidalis,but without seeing whether there's reptans nearby, no way of knowing for sure.